# Can not insert arabic data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, arabic

I've made a C# application using SQL Server, when I try to insert Arabic data from application, it will be appear in SQL Server as `????`.

I inserted data using this stored procedure:

```
Create proc [dbo].[ADD_PRODUCT]
    @id_cat int,
    @ID_product varchar(30),
    @label_product varchar(50),
    @Qte_in_stock int,
    @price varchar(50),
    @image_products image
as
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[products]
           ([ID_product]
           ,[Label_product]
           ,[Qte_in_stock]
           ,[price]
           ,[image_products]
           ,[id_cat])
     VALUES
           (@ID_product,
           @label_product,
           @Qte_in_stock,
           @price,
           @image_products,
           @id_cat)
```

I know that when I insert Arabic in SQL Server, I use this command

```
Insert into test ([Employee Name]) values (N'سارة')
```

But I do not know how to make this in my stored procedure.

Comment: Your columns are varchar, but you want to insert unicode data which needs Nvarchar.

Comment: `but I don not know how to make this in stored procedure` - Make what?

Comment: before the value, add the character N

Comment: You just need to pass a `nvarchar` as variable, not a `varchar`. Also your target column needs to be `nvarchar`, as pointed out by @shree.pat18

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `nvarchar` instead of the `varchar` type you are using.

Beside that, are you sure you want to use `varchar` for price? That should probably be types like `decimal(10,2)` or `money`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NVARCHAR` instead of `VARCHAR`

Try below,

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[ADD_PRODUCT]
(
    @id_cat INT
   ,@ID_product VARCHAR(30)
   ,@label_product NVARCHAR(50)
   ,@Qte_in_stock INT
   ,@price VARCHAR(50)
   ,@image_products IMAGE
)
AS

INSERT INTO [dbo].[products]
  (
    [ID_product]
   ,[Label_product] -- This also have the same datatype - NVARCHAR
   ,[Qte_in_stock]
   ,[price]
   ,[image_products]
   ,[id_cat]
  )
VALUES
  (
    @ID_product
   ,@label_product
   ,@Qte_in_stock
   ,@price
   ,@image_products
   ,@id_cat
  )
```